# UItextView hide in UIScrollview on tap

Tags: iphone

I have an UIScrollView (with 40+ pages) with UITextview added as subview on every page.
What i want to do is that on single tap, i want to hide the UITextField on all pages?
How should I do it?
I am trying to do like this in hadle tap method:

`textview.hidden = YES;`

But it is hiding text view only on last page, not on all pages.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you use 40 separate textview or a single textview?

Comment: I got you, Can you provide some code lines related to adding textViews.?

Answer (score 2):

You can do, instead of `textview.hidden = YES;` the following:

```
for(id object in objScrollView.subviews)
{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        UITextView *tmpObj= (UITextView *)object;
        [tmpObj setHidden:!tmpObj.hidden];
    }
}
```

Put the above code in tap method.